# javascript - map items and extract items from sub array conditionally

Tags: javascript

How to extract items from a 2d array.

```
const array = [["1", "3"],["4", "3"]]
const itemToExclude = "3"
```

Use `itemToExclude` variable to exclude item from result (in this case `3`)

**Expected result** is `["1", "4"]`

```js
const array = [["1", "3"],["4", "3"]]
const itemToExclude = "3"

const result = array.map((item) => {
   return item.map((subitem) => {
      return subitem
      // exclude itemToExclude
      })
    })
        
  console.log(result)
```

Comment: What would the result be if the array didn’t contain the item to exclude? What would the result be for `array = [ [ "1", "3" ], [ "4", "2" ] ]`? Is the result just going to be a flat list? If so, why not simply [`flat`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and [`filter`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and filter

```js
const array = [
  ["1", "3"],
  ["4", "3"]
]
const itemToExclude = "3"

const result = array.flat().filter(item => item !== itemToExclude);
console.log(result)
```

You can also use reduce and inside the callback check if the element is not equals to `itemToExclude`

```js
const array = [
  ["1", "3"],
  ["4", "3"]
]
const itemToExclude = "3"

const result = array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  for (let i of curr) {
    if (i !== itemToExclude) {
      acc.push(i)
    }
  }

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your inner method should be [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) as you're trying to remove items from the inner array. For each `subitem` you can return `true` for the items you want to keep, which can be done by checking `subitem !== itemToExclude`. You can also change the outer `.map()` to a [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to concatenate all results returned by the inner `.filter()` calls together into one resulting array.

See working example below:

```js
const array = [["1", "3"],["4", "3"]];
const itemToExclude = "3";

const result = array.flatMap((item) => item.filter((subitem) => subitem !== itemToExclude));
     
console.log(result);
```

Comment: isnt the map extra work in this scenario

Comment: @cmgchess Extra work compared to what exactly? I guess it does two iterations of the inner array, one for the `.filter()` call and then one for the merging of the filtered inner array into the resulting array, which you can avoid by using two loops and an if-statement. Compared to `.flat()` + `.filter()` though it should be the same amount of work (considering that `.flat()` needs to loop through the outer array and all inner array elements just like `.flatMap()` does)

Comment: @NickParsons, Could you please help me here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/74580671/15916627